# Does Performing DML in Remote DB de-instantiates all packages in the local DB

Tags: oracle, distributed, dml

I have a package variable in local site which i am initiating a value and after lot of processing i call a remote db procedure which performs some DML.I can find that processing which depends on the package variable which i initialized is not working.But the same processing is working if i dont call the remote db procedure

Also both local and remote db are oracle

For example in a local session

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE LOCAL_PKG
AS
PKG_VARIABLE NUMBER(1):=0;
--other local statements
END;
```

Now i set the value of this variable to a different one in a local procedure

```
LOCAL_PKG.PKG_VARIABLE:=1;
```

Then i call i remote procedure

```
IF NOT REMOTE_PROC@REMOTEDB THEN-- this performs DML in remote database
 --some local statements 
END IF;
-- other local statments

-- other local processing
```

Now in the local database i check this condition and then do some processing.It is this part which is not working

```
IF LOCAL_PKG.PKG_VARIABLE=1
THEN
-- do some processing 
ELSE
-- do nothing
END IF;
```

So my question is does calling DML in remote database De-instantiates all packages in the local session ????

Comment: This is all in the same local session?

Comment: yes in the same local session

Comment: i checked the documentation for distributed transactions but it is not clear about how the sessions are managed

Comment: Remote DML over a DB link shouldn't affect your local session or package instance. It seems much more likely that the local processing is resetting the variable after the remote call (in 'some local statements'?) but presumably you're already sure you've ruled that out. Can you come up with a small but complete example that demonstrates what you're seeing? I tried a simplistic version but it didn't reproduce this, so something important is missing somewhere.

Comment: found out the issue it is in --do some processing inside IF LOCAL_PKG.PKG_VARIABLE=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling DML in remote database is not de-instantiating any package variable in my local session

The local variable is reset inside  `--do some processing` in the below piece of code

```
IF LOCAL_PKG.PKG_VARIABLE=1
THEN
-- do some processing 
ELSE
-- do nothing
END IF;
```